# Couldn't get my PHP Laravel app to work in MS Azure App Service by following MS knowledge page

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-web-app-service

I was able to follow the Microsoft PHP tutorial page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-php-mysql-app?pivots=platform-linux
with their sample application OK. But once I copied my own Laravel application in and uploaded, my application did not work - even no home page ( it works locally on my machine).

I feel something is wrong with this section
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux#change-site-root
"Change site root
...To work around this limitation, add an .htaccess file to your repository root with the following content...
"
Q: What repository root is it talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root of your repository is the main folder containing the Laravel app. i.e. the main directory in which the app, database, config etc directories are there - .env, composer.json file is there.

As per the instructions in docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux#change-site-root,  you need to create .htaccess file with the provided code in the main folder

```
# Laravel Project (directory structure)

|-app
|-config
|-database
|-public
|-resources
|-routes
|-storage
|-tests
|-.env
|-.gitattributes
|-.gitignore
|-.htaccess       # Create .htaccess at the root of Laravel project
|-artisan
|-composer.json
|-package.json
|-phpunit.xml
|-README.md
|-server.php
|-webpack.mix.js
```

Comment: Thanks! Resolved after I added same .htaccess from the MS sample code in this repository root. BTW, did you exercise the same page before? It is a long page and took me a few hours before I narrow my focus on the .htaccess.

Comment: @EricY Nope I'm not using azure, had a look at the page after reading your question. Anyways if the answer helped you solve the issue in question pls remember to mark it as accepted for the benefit of subsequent visitors.